# How to reduce Logger.getLogger(...) boilerplate in every class

Tags: java, logging, refactoring, code-duplication

To use logger with Java, for now I'm using code like this:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
FileHandler fh;

try {

  // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter
  fh = new FileHandler("c:\\MyLogFile.log", true);
  logger.addHandler(fh);
  logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
  SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
  fh.setFormatter(formatter);

  // the following statement is used to log any messages   
  logger.log(Level.WARNING,"My first log");

} catch (SecurityException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it always disturbs me somewhat to add this for every class file:

```
Logger l = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
```

How could I refactor out this duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better recommended way for logging, which could be less intrusive/less repeative but offers the same or even better functions?

You could make `l` a `private static` or `private` field of the class, but apart from that there is no significant improvement.

(There are some bad ideas, like a `public static` "global" variable, or a `private static` declaration in a "universal" base class.  But those are BAD IDEAS ... not better ways.)

But, hey, one line of code to declare your local logger object is hardly "intrusive" ... is it?

Comment: Not everybody does this. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Logging in every class file is a right way,  alougth it is looks a little redundancy.

The important function for logging is that record exception. If we want to directly find where occurs the exception, we should know the class name and the method name.

But you maybe be forget to logging when catch exception.

Answer (score 0):

We're using reflection and static fields and this API: http://commons.forgerock.org/bom/apidocs/org/forgerock/i18n/slf4j/LocalizedLogger.html#getLoggerForThisClass()

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But I do wish to involve as few libs as possible. I always believe the simplest is the best. If I can avoid log4j, I'll try to avoid it....

Comment: I was not suggesting you use this library. Rather that you looked at how it is done and see if you like the approach, and maybe copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use project lombok to do this:

[project lombok is here](https://projectlombok.org/features/log)

The following is the example from their webpage should it ever not be available. To be clear it still generates the statements in your resulting bytecode, but it stops the bolierplate, now you'll have a smaller statement to but in, its horses for courses but the project team I currently work on like it.

```
import lombok.extern.java.Log;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Log
public class LogExample {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    log.error("Something's wrong here");
  }
}

@Slf4j
public class LogExampleOther {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    log.error("Something else is wrong here");
  }
}

@CommonsLog(topic="CounterLog")
public class LogExampleCategory {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    log.error("Calling the 'CounterLog' with a message");
  }
}
Vanilla Java
 public class LogExample {
  private static final java.util.logging.Logger log = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogExample.class.getName());

  public static void main(String... args) {
    log.error("Something's wrong here");
  }
}

public class LogExampleOther {
  private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExampleOther.class);

  public static void main(String... args) {
    log.error("Something else is wrong here");
  }
}

public class LogExampleCategory {
  private static final org.apache.commons.logging.Log log = org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog("CounterLog");

  public static void main(String... args) {
    log.error("Calling the 'CounterLog' with a message");
  }
}
```